# Numpy fromfunction - is it a bug?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

Python 3.6.4, Anaconda, Windows 10 x64, numpy 1.13.3.

```
>>> q = np.fromfunction(lambda i: 7, (3, ), dtype=np.float32)
>>> q
7
>>> q = np.fromfunction(lambda i: 7 + 0*i, (3, ), dtype=np.float32)
>>> q
array([ 7.,  7.,  7.], dtype=float32)
```

Is it expected? Basically, what I'm trying to do is to fill array from binary stream, but

```
>>> q = np.fromfunction(lambda i: struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))[0], (3, ), dtype=np.float32)
```

won't work - only scalar is assigned

Comment: Looks like `numpy.fromfunction`'s confusing docs claim another victim. (They used to be even worse.)

Comment: `np.fromfunction` is Python code that you can read and test for yourself.  Looks like it does `your_func(*np.indices((3,)))`.  I don't think it is used very often.  I haven't used it.